# Elasticsearch Java API: Object mapping for [eventDefinitions] tried to parse field [null] as object, but found a concrete value?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-mapping

I am trying to make a mapping for the following document work:

```
{
  "eventDatabase": "abc",
  "usageLibraryEventType": "ABC",
  "name": "Prionti",
  "namespace": "Prionti's namespace",
  "latestBuildTimestamp": 1581348323634,
  "flattenedEventProperties": [
    "User Id"
  ],
  "eventDefinitions": [
    {
      "buildInfo": {
        "baseVersion": "1",
        "branch": "master",
        "buildName": "something.com",
        "orgName": "Prionti's org",
        "repoName": "myrepo",
        "buildTimestamp": 1581348323634,
        "packageName": "myrepo",
        "packagePath": "",
        "resolvedVersion": "1.2920",
        "rootModuleName": "repo",
        "rootPackagePath": ""
      },
      "eventKey": "myEvent",
      "eventDefinition": {
        "name": "myName",
        "namespace": "myNamespace",
        "meta": {
          "description": "No description available",
          "database": "myDatabase",
          "owner": null,
          "codeOwners": [
            "Prionti Nasir"
          ],
          "imgSrc": null,
          "isPublic": null,
          "yamlSrc": {
            "packageName": "my-package",
            "packageVersion": "static-1.2920",
            "relativePath": "something.yaml"
          }
        },
        "properties": {
          "userId": {
            "type": "number",
            "options": null,
            "isOptional": false,
            "description": null
          }
        },
        "class": "interaction"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I will exclude the buildInfo and a few other fields, so I created a mapping accordingly:

```
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "number_of_replicas": "2",
      "number_of_shards": "25",
      "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
          "autocomplete": {
            "filter": [
              "lowercase",
              "autocomplete_filter"
            ],
            "tokenizer": "standard",
            "type": "custom"
          },
          "prefixMatch": {
            "filter": [
              "lowercase"
            ],
            "tokenizer": "standard",
            "type": "custom"
          }
        },
        "filter": {
          "autocomplete_filter": {
            "min_gram": "3",
            "max_gram": "10",
            "type": "edge_ngram"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "usageLibraryEventType": {
      "dynamic": false,
      "properties": {
        "eventDatabase": {
          "properties": {
            "name": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          },
          "enabled": "false"
        },
        "eventType": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "autocomplete"
        },
        "name": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "autocomplete"
        },
        "namespace": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "autocomplete"
        },
        "latestBuildTimestamp": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "flattenedEventProperties": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "eventDefinitions": {
          "properties": {
            "eventKey": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
            },
            "eventDefinition": {
              "properties": {
                "name": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "index": "no"
                },
                "namespace": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "index": "no"
                },
                "meta": {
                  "properties": {
                    "description": {
                      "type": "string",
                      "analyzer": "prefixMatch"
                    },
                    "owner": {
                      "type": "string",
                      "index": "not_analyzed",
                      "null_value" : "N/A"
                    },
                    "codeOwners": {
                      "type": "string",
                      "index": "not_analyzed",
                      "null_value" : "N/A"
                    }
                  }
                },
                "class": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "index": "not_analyzed"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is giving me a MapperParsingException. `eventDefinitions` is supposed to be a list of json objects each of which will contain `buildInfo`, `eventKey` and `eventDefinition`. `eventDefinition` further contains json objects as you can see.

```
@POST
  public UsageLibraryEventType indexEventType(UsageLibraryEventType usageLibraryEventType) {
    elasticsearchIndexerClient.addDocumentRequest(
        new IndexRequest(config.getUsageLibrarySourceTopic(), TYPE)
            .source(
                "eventDatabase", usageLibraryEventType.getEventDatabase(),
                "eventType", usageLibraryEventType.getUsageLibraryEventType(),
                "name", usageLibraryEventType.getName(),
                "namespace", usageLibraryEventType.getNamespace(),
                // fix these field names
                "latestBuildTimestamp", usageLibraryEventType.getLatestBuildTimestamp(),
                "flattenedEventProperties", usageLibraryEventType.getFlattenedEventProperties(),
                "eventDefinitions", usageLibraryEventType.getEventDefinitions()),
        config.getUsageLibrarySourceTopic())
        .join();
    return usageLibraryEventType;
  }
```

(`eventDefinitions` is a list of `EventDefinitionWithBuildInfo`, and each `EventDefinitionWithBuildInfo` contains `buildInfo`, `eventKey` and `eventDefinition`. `EventDefinition` further contains a few fields and an object called `meta`.  Although I have mapped all of this out in the mapping, I don't explicitly hand over values for each of the fields to the last branch in the tree. There's no way for me to enter each field in each `eventDefinitionWithBuildInfo` and then in `eventDefinition` separately of course, so I have to give it the list, as a result of which it does not get mapped all the way to the last unit. What can I do about this? Should I define new types called `EventDefinitionWithBuildInfo`  and  `EventDefinition` ?

Comment: which version of es you are using?

Comment: If you post  small example of your java code that can reproduce this error, we should be able to help you out!

Comment: @IanGabes posted!

Comment: Your java objects cannot be serialized to JSON like this. You are passing the Elasticsearch client stuff like "Lists of EventDefinition". ES has no idea how to convert that into JSON. You can do this with libraries like Jackson. Try using Jackson to convert your UsageLibraryEventType into JSON, then give ES that string.

Comment: @IanGabes you are a hero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@IanGabes is a savior. I spent my weekend crying and trying to get this working. But my object is so nested, so layered, and I was expecting ES to detect the inner fields on its own. I showed this to so many people and they were clueless. Then, as I was hopelessly watching Rick and Morty with chips falling off of my mouth, @IanGabes came like an angel and asked me to simply use Jackson to convert my object to Json, and that it will not deserialize to the last unit the way I was doing it. Thank you. You rock, I suck.