# How to make elasticsearch parse a list of json objects of the same type?

Tags: java, json, elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elk

For one of the properties of a document I am trying to index, called `eventDefinitions`, I am sending a list of json objects which in turn have inner fields. It ends up parsed as a single string. There is no way for me to send each field separately, I can only send a list of json objects for the `eventDefinitions` property. How can I make ES parse it as a list of json objects and also recognize each of the fields in each json object according to my mapping?

Comment: Try reproducing the problem with curl/dev tools, or show us your code. My first guess is that it is a simple mistake in how you  are ingesting, but its hard to say without seeing your code!

Comment: @IanGabes my code is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60358254/mapperparsingexceptionobject-mapping-for-eventdefinitions-tried-to-parse-fiel

Comment: @IanGabes I got rid of the Exception by removing fields which have null values (which is concerning, because the null values should have been withstood by the "null_value" tags - I think that didn't work because the whole thing is parsed as a string). But the problem still remains. I need to, say, access eventDefinitions -> eventDefinition -> meta -> description, but how will I do so?

Comment: Ok!I'll move my attention to your other question. Try not to open more than one question for the same problem, it helps everyone out!